# How can I track app usage?

Tags: applications

Is there a way to show usage stats for installed applications on my Android phone?  I'd like to know how much I use my apps and if there are any I can get rid of (because I don't use them).

Answer (score 21):

This functionality is already inbuilt into Android.

1. Open your dailer
2. Enter `*#*#4636#*#*`
3. Select *Usage statistics*
4. Sort by *Launch Count*.

As far as I know these statistics get reset every time you reset your phone. Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe these stats are reset every time the phone reboots. It's not the prettiest view, but it does allow for sorting not only by Launch Count, but also Usage Time, and App Name. I would mark this as the answer to OP's question.

Comment: Doesn't work under Samsung Alpha with lollipop

Comment: Doesn't work on Mi Redmi note 4

Answer (score 6):

Try [Spare Parts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts) app from the Play Store (it's built into some older custom ROMs).  Under the "Device info" heading there is "Usage statistics" which should give information you're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't work under Samsung Alpha with lollipop. Used to work before upgrade

Comment: **Spare Parts** is a broken link

Comment: Fixed link updated.

Answer (score 3):

[SystemPanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1) provides historic app usage statistics.

Answer (score 3):

I also have developed an app called "App Usage Tracker". You can [download it here from the market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agrvaibhav.AppUsageTracking) .

Comment: Nice application +

Answer (score 1):

I developed a free app called "AppUsage". You can find it [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartappers.appusage).

Comment: It may be a good idea to note your affiliation with the app (for those that don't take too much notice of usernames etc)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that an app is running doesn't mean you're using it. `Settings > About Phone > Battery Use` will give you a run down of what has been using juice on your phone, a good clue to whether the app is doing anything. You can also run a task manager -- [How To Geek suggests Advanced Task Cleaner](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25319/complete-guide-to-maximizing-your-android-phones-battery-life/). Both of these options will tell you what is running, not what isn't running, but you can extrapolate from there.