# Is there a program which will log each program I start on my Android device?

Tags: applications, logging

I am looking for a program that will **count each start of a program** on my Android device.

Over time, you install quit a lot of programs.

It would be nice to see **how many times you actually start** these programs over time.

That could give a **good indication whether you should leave the program on the device**, or not.

Comment: See this question about application usage http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/how-can-i-track-app-usage Some of the apps might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the phone information dial code if it works.

In your dialer enter `*#*#4636#*#*` to get to the phone info screen.

On my Spica running 2.1 Eclair, the last option of USAGE STATISTICS shows the usage time (in milliseconds) and the no. of times an app has been launched.

At first glance, it does however seem to be a log restricted from the time the phone was last booted.

Comment: That's great - it indeed is a count since last boot, but it's a start. Thanks.