# How often app is used?

Tags: applications, htc-wildfire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are my most frequently used apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18774/what-are-my-most-frequently-used-apps)

Is there any app, that can tell me which applications I use most?

I want to optimize my shortcuts to put most clicked icons first.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See  eldarerathis's comment for an app that does this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545691/how-to-keep-track-of-which-applications-used-most-in-android-phone

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114498/is-there-a-way-to-monitor-and-record-which-applications-have-started-recently

Both of these questions and the answers the receive suggests that it isn't possible for an application to monitor which other apps are being used. Quite a shame really, I would be interested to see what I use the most.

Comment: See [What are my most frequently used apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18774)