# How do I know when an app was used in Android?

Tags: applications, history

Is there any way to tell when an app was being used in an Android phone?

I am specifically interested in the camera and gallery functions. I believe my roommate went through my photos without asking, and I've tried to view the cache for the Gallery app but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Is this even on the right track? He had it for a twenty minute interval, and I want to see if the Gallery was accessed during that period of time.

Answer (score 18):

Android allows usage stats to be seen from GUI. Here's how you can see it. ([Source](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2011/05/23/usagestats/), by Kevin Swartz)

1. In your default dialer, type `*#*#4636#*#*`. It would open a window named **Testing** which is a sub-setting of **Settings** app.
2. Go to **Usage Statistics**.

   [image: IMG:]

   **For Lollipop**:

   - Sort the time in **Sort by:** based on **Usage time** or  **Last time used** or  **App name**.
   - The order of entries are **App**, **Last time used**, and **Usage time**.

     <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

     [image: IMG:] [image: IMG:] [image: IMG:]

     **For Jelly Bean 4.2.1 to Kitkat 4.4.2**:

     - Sort the time in **Sort by:** based on **Usage time** or  **Launch count** or **App name**.
     - The order of entries are **App**, **Count**, and **Usage time**.

     <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

     [image: IMG:] [image: IMG:] [image: IMG:]

     The usage time in these Android versions is shown in milliseconds (ms). You may do calculation on your own, or try a conversion tool like [this](http://www.unitconversion.org/time/milliseconds-to-minutes-conversion.html) to instantly convert them into minutes.

### Don't forget ADB

Alternatively, you can directly jump into the **Usage Statistics** window using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb). Enter this command:

For Android Lollipop:

```
   adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.UsageStatsActivity
```

For Android 4.2.1 to 4.4.2:

```
   adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.UsageStats
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5494891) if you're interested in knowing the role of parameters in those commands.

You can also do `adb shell dumpsys usagestats` ([Source](http://jhshi.me/2014/04/02/get-package-usage-statistics-in-android/), by Jinghao Shi) which for Android 4.2.1 and 4.4.2 didn't give anything more useful than already covered in  screenshots posted above for them.

Lollipop shows more end-user comprehensible output in comparison to its predecessors,

```
In-memory daily stats
  timeRange="8/29/2015, 8:34 AM â 8/30/2015, 1:41 AM" 
    packages
      package=com.android.documentsui totalTime="00:07" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.browser totalTime="00:02" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.camera2 totalTime="00:05" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:37 AM" 
...
...
events
      time="8/30/2015, 1:34 AM" type=MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND package=com.android.deskclock class=com.android.deskclock.DeskClock 
      time="8/30/2015, 1:34 AM" type=MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND package=com.android.dialer class=com.android.incallui.InCallActivity 
      time="8/30/2015, 1:34 AM" type=MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND package=com.android.dialer class=com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity 
...
...
In-memory weekly stats
  timeRange="8/27/2015, 5:30 AM â 8/30/2015, 1:41 AM" 
    packages
      package=com.android.documentsui totalTime="00:07" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.browser totalTime="00:02" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.camera2 totalTime="00:05" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:37 AM"
...
...
In-memory monthly stats
  timeRange="8/9/2015, 8:34 AM â 8/30/2015, 1:41 AM" 
    packages
      package=com.android.documentsui totalTime="00:07" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.browser totalTime="00:02" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.camera2 totalTime="00:05" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:37 AM"
...
...
In-memory yearly stats
  timeRange="12/21/2014, 5:30 AM â 8/30/2015, 1:41 AM" 
    packages
      package=com.android.documentsui totalTime="00:07" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.browser totalTime="00:02" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:35 AM" 
      package=com.android.camera2 totalTime="00:05" lastTime="8/30/2015, 1:37 AM"
```

Now you can browse the list to find Camera and Gallery app, and see their "last time used" value, for Lollipop, that is. Unfortunately, the info in this section wouldn't help the devices running predecessor of Lollipop, unless the device is rooted, or you find an app that can give you package statistics.

Also, in your particular case, all of this info would be helpful only if you've had not launched the Camera, Gallery, or a particular app of your interest after your friend was done using the phone, since the time-stamp for that app gets updated to the new "Last time used", for all Android versions I mentioned.

---

**The following section would work if the device is rooted.**

---

### For Jelly Bean (4.2.1) to Kitkat (4.4.2)

Android keeps a log of when  an app (it's component) was last used. You can head down to `/data/system/usagestats/` using a [file explorer with root access](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file+explorer+root), or using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).

There would be a file named `usage-history.xml` and some other files with naming convention as `usage-YYMMDD` where:

- YYYY - Year
- MM - Month
- DD - Date

E.g. `usage-20150729` is the file created on July 29, 2015.

That `.xml` is a plain XML file, so you should be able to view it in a  text editor. Those `usage-YYMMDD` are `data` files (`charset=binary`) and my text editor [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) couldn't open them in human-readable form. However, `cat <FILE>` command does the job, so as the Android app [QuickEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit), not completely I should add.

The basic template of entries in that `.xml` file is:

```
<pkg name="">
  <comp name="" />
  <comp name="" />
  ...
  <comp name="" />
</pkg>
```

E.g. These are the following entries for the [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) app:

```
<pkg name="dev.ukanth.ufirewall">
  <comp name="dev.ukanth.ufirewall.MainActivity" lrt="1438134244890" />
  <comp name="dev.ukanth.ufirewall.widget.ToggleWidgetOldActivity" lrt="1435337932669" />
  <comp name="dev.ukanth.ufirewall.HelpActivity" lrt="1416601650972" />
  ...
</pkg>
```

The `lrt` against every component (`comp`) is the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). To make it human readable, use [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) or anything that can convert Unix time into human readable time.

E.g. `1438134244890` is the Unix time when I accessed the AFWall+'s main activity (it's default view) and the converted time is `Wed, 29 Jul 2015 01:44:04 GMT`, which is correct.

As for the content in `usage-YYMMDD`, you'll see activities of the apps you visited on that day. There is no time-stamp there.

### For Lollipop

Lollipop has considerable changes in regard to usage statistics collection of an app. See official note by  Google [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#System).

The concept of  `usage-history.xml` and `usage-YYMMDD` doesn't apply here. Instead, you get directories named `daily`, `monthly`, `weekly`, `yearly`. All of them has files which you guessed it right, having numeral names, nothing but Unix Time like `1440374400000`.

A typical file under `daily` has the content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<usagestats version="1" endTime="66355190">
    <packages>
        <package lastTimeActive="66153798" package="com.android.providers.media" timeActive="2974" lastEvent="2" />
        <package lastTimeActive="66329769" package="net.dinglisch.android.taskerm" timeActive="64172" lastEvent="2" />
        <package lastTimeActive="66150806" package="android" timeActive="1942" lastEvent="2" />
...
...
    <event-log>
        <event time="43080692" package="android" type="5" fs="1065353216" mcc="404" mnc="97" />
        <event time="43087204" package="com.android.launcher3" class="com.android.launcher3.Launcher" type="2" />
        <event time="43087329" package="com.android.settings" class="com.android.settings.Settings" type="1" />
```

Now this is actually the same thing that we saw in `usagestat`'s  output but the timing is in its raw form. I've no idea how to understand the time here let alone convert it into human-readable form. [Developers should be able to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager).

If you what it is and how to convert (*as an end-user*) then please let me know it or post an answer here.

---

Comment: Have you tried opening the config file with Notepad++. I have no root so I can't check myself.

Comment: @Lucky Didn't try Windows; using Slackware Linux here. You may try opening it in your system. [Here is the file](http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/1FYv0x5G/file.html). It doesn't seem to hold any configuration, so I possibly wouldn't call it a config file. :)

Comment: Could open in Notepadd++ and Sublime Text editors. Sublime opens it as as HEX data.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot for Notepad ++?

Comment: Here's how it look in [Notepad++](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P67P7.png) and [Sublime Text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX2Zo.png)

Comment: Plain ASCII XML here for my tabbi running 4.1.2. @Firelord: As I have no 5.x device, could you please at least include the file names used there? Thanks a lot! // For those who are curious: [this is what they look like there](http://pastebin.com/bDQT1ifZ).

Comment: @Firelord what a coincident: I've just re-checked your post right know before seeing the notification :) I would upvote it again if I could, very thorough and detailed. Now we just need the missing "timing" detail for Lollipop … Thanks for your hard work!

Comment: As [per user Mel](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/168369): *UPDATE: The time (event time="43087329") is the delta/time elapsed in milliseconds since the time the log was created. So 1440374400000+43087329, and then convert into something readable using a Unix convertor.*

Comment: adb all the way.

Answer (score 2):

If your phone is last used or if you want to find out apps which runs/connected on internet like(Browsers, Clash of Clans etc) the last used activity is recorded under the my activity in your google account. You can find that out by visiting https://myactivity.google.com and click on Android.