# How to convert time-stamps into human readable form written in a usage-stats file of Android Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

The file under consideration is any file under `/data/system/usagestats/0/daily/`. The entries it has are like:

```
<package lastTimeActive="77497976" package="com.android.settings" timeActive="471657" lastEvent="2" /> 
<package lastTimeActive="50486897" package="com.android.dialer" timeActive="180327" lastEvent="2" />
<package lastTimeActive="83158956" package="com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet" timeActive="461860" lastEvent="2" />
<package lastTimeActive="59444603" package="com.slovoed.oald" timeActive="405608" lastEvent="2" />
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/bQexC3w3) is the complete text for the file `1438905600000`.

The value `77497976` doesn't seem to be Unix Time, and `471657` seems to be [milliseconds](http://www.unitconversion.org/time/milliseconds-to-minutes-conversion.html).

I added that value into the value mentioned in file name i.e. `1438905600000` + `77497976`, and the converted resultant of `1438983097976` [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/) doesn't reflect the actual result shown in GUI here:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; screenshot was taken on Aug 8, 2015 at 05:08 AM)</sub>

[image: IMG: Screenshot of Usage Statistics]

Package name of apps shown in screenshot whose raw time-stamps you can see in the file:

- Settings → `com.android.settings`
- Dialer → `com.android.dialer`
- Launcher3 → `com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet`
- SQLite Editor → `com.speedsoftware.sqleditor`
- Titanium Backup → `com.keramidas.titaniumbackup`
- OALD → `com.slovoed.oald`
- ES File Explorer → `com.estrongs.android.pop`
- Clock → `com.android.deskclock`

`adb shell su -c 'dumpsys usagestats'` is of no help since it gives no output to me.

[In Android 4.x, it is easy to understand the time-stamp](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/116633/96277) (mainly the "last time used") because Unix Time is written in the logs, and you can convert it into human readable time easily.

I looked at [UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html), [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html), [UsageStatsActivity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.0.2_r1/com/android/settings/UsageStatsActivity.java#UsageStatsActivity.UsageStatsAdapter) but couldn't understand how the time gets converted.

---

Alternatively, is there a schema which Lollipop follows to write entries in those usage-stats file? Perhaps, that can help to figure out in conversion?

I'm using a rooted OnePlus One running CM12.

Comment: `timeActive` seems to be corresponding to "Usage Time" (i.e. how long the app was active) in ms, as you assumed. The others don't seem to make a match, even considering time-zone differences (Aug 7 23:31:37 from what I've calculated using `date -d @<unixtime>`; times again in ms). Maybe you could [edit] your question and include numbers for the other apps so we might see a pattern? "Last time used" somehow suggest user action (direct invocation); maybe the settings app was triggered "indirectly"?

Comment: I actually posted the full file [here](http://pastebin.com/bQexC3w3) as mentioned. Also, I made sure that entries in the screenshot and the time I copied those remains the same. Are you asking something else?

Comment: Ooops – I revoke that part of my previous comment, missed that link, sorry. But that makes it even more strange, as the entries don't match: from the file, DeskClock was LRU; I don't see it in the screenshot. From the screenshot, TiBu was used shortly; I can't find that in the file. I'm confused. // Btw: does the `usage-history.xml` still exist with Lollipop, and in the same place as with 4.x? [This blogpost](http://freeandroidforensics.blogspot.de/2014/11/some-artifacts-in-datasystem-directory.html) suggests as much.

Comment: What I'm playing at: You might have picked the wrong file to compare with. Your screenshot is newer (Aug 8, 5 am) than the file (Aug 7, 2 am); on Aug 8, 2 am Android could have started a new file (if it does so all 24h that is). As that's just argued by the file name: what does `ls -l` give for its last "touch"?

Comment: Fresh piece: This is the recent screenshot I took after using ES File Explorer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wdMbY.png. Here is the stats file I immediately captured after closing Explorer: http://pastebin.com/X4A5Knha

Comment: `ls -l 1438992000000` gives me `2015-08-08 22:39` which is weird because it's not correct as per screenshot. Even if it's GMT, it's incorrect since it should   be -05:30 from the screenshot in its output as Android outputs GMT in shell.

Comment: Agreed. And again, the file doesn't reflect the screenshot: the top 3 from the file (if ordered by lastTimeActive) are not included with the screenshot at the position I'd expect them – but a lot closer to the bottom. And vice-versa. Note: EndTime matches lastTimeActive of Trebuchet (Launcher), making that the last-used app (and ruling out "RTL" writing of numbers, which I almost started to suspect). Again: Is the `/data/system/usagestats/usage-history.xml` available to check against?

Comment: The concept of having a single `usage-history.xml` in only applicable until Kitkat. Since Lollipop, all the usage-stats are in folders *viz.* daily, weekly, monthly and yearly. The files their are plain XML but extension is missing, Their name is the UNIX TIME when they were created. Usually created at 00:00 GMT.

Comment: Also, in the recent screenshot, the entries of Settings, Dialer, and Launcher3 is correct before ES File Explorer, since I entered the code in dialer to launch Testing settings, and I visited the dialer using launcher. All of this happened after using Explorer app, so the screenshot is absolutely correct. The issue is with the file!

Comment: Have you been able to solve the mystery meanwhile?

Comment: Nope. Primarily because I abandoned this issue, and time, unfortunately and as of now, doesn't permit me to do research at all.