# How to log all user interaction on my device?

Tags: applications, security, logging, user-interface

I would like to know whether on an Android device it is possible to:

1. Log the date and time of every time a password is entered on my Android phone (this security measure would mean that if someone in my home sees me enter a password without me noticing it, and then uses it to log into my phone, I would then be able to see whether this happened or not to take care of my suspicion).
2. As an extra step, I would like to log all activity once the login screen is bypassed as well (for instance the date an time and application name for each time an application is opened. This is because, while my phone is password protected, once I make the screen go blank by pressing the hardware button on the right, some time goes by until a password is required: I have things set up this way so that I don't have to enter the password just so often). So, is there a way to log all user activity when the lock screen has been bypassed as well?

The device I have is a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo running Android KitKat 4.4.2.
The device has been rooted.

Thanks!!!

Comment: A bypass technically is a mockery of the security of a particular thing for which bypass has been used. In your second case, I see no scenario of bypass. It's just a user (not you) entering your password and gaining access in a technically legitimate manner. Please explain what kind of bypass scenario is supposed to be considered in second point. How do you technically differentiate between your access and the other person's access to the system? I currently find no difference.

Comment: Also see [How do I know when an app was used in Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/116633)

Comment: @Firelord, if I leave my phone on the table, and know I didn't touch it in the last 8 hours, and go back to it and see that a password has been entered correctly (1.) and that some applications have been opened (2.), then I know there has been an intruder accessing the stuff on my phone. No, I don't distinguish between myself and someone else. I just happen to remember when I last personally interacted with my phone.

Comment: @Firelord, I've tried following the instructions in your link, but it does not work on my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo. The error I get is that there is a connection problem and that the code I entered is not valid.

Comment: John, in that link I also mentioned alternative way using ADB. Does that also not work in your device?

Comment: Well, for one I cannot get to the Testing window, is there some other code I need to type on my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo KitKat to get this to show up. Secondly, when I am on vacation I don't usually bring my computer with me, so I cannot really rely on using 'adb shell' to get to the last time, especially since I may use the app after someone accesses it, and this would overwrite the last time with some other time, not desirable.

Comment: I'm wondering if I could have an app built (e.g. on freelancer.com or elance.com) to support the behavior I'm looking for, or whether what I'm afeter is impossible to carry out. Thanks.