# Checking activity of unknown user on my phone

Tags: security, history

Yesterday I took my new phone to a mobile service shop... I wanted them to put a protection layer on my display. I have a pattern lock on my phone so I just put the display to sleep and gave it to him. He went to another room, and **15 minutes later** he gave me the phone back.

**My questions are:** even though I have a pattern to unlock phone how can I make sure that he did not do anything suspicious to it? He was very strange. Could he have guessed or cracked the code? Is there a way to inject some kind of harmful code via usb cable? How can I check all the activity, not just browser history or `history.google.com` but all the list of apps that were turned on? Or any other activity that might cause problems to me. Also, is there also anyway to inject some kind of harmfull code to a blocked phone using usb cable? And lets say that code would delete the pattern and gain the access to phone ?

I want to hear from a security expert. Should I do a factory reset would it delete everything that might be inserted by him to the phone ?  just to make sure?

Or am I being paranoid? Thanks

Comment: What Android version are you running?

Comment: 6.0 Marshamllow ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know when an app was used in Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116625/how-do-i-know-when-an-app-was-used-in-android)

Comment: no its not duplicate beeshy i dont talk just about app usage at all.

Comment: You can see the question above to detect if any app was accessed during the time it was away from you. Second part of your question about injecting code is theoretically possible but better asked in security SE

Comment: well there are probably too many ways to harm the phone if you want to , but anyway even if there would be some kind of virus which i doubt why would a service man do it , but if yes then what is the best solution ? throw the phone to trash ? do factory reset ? i want to be 100% sure that if there is something wrong it wont be there anymore , by wrong i mean virus , changed setting , password leak , etc.

Comment: Go thorough the answers. Your question talks of *how do I check app activity, list of apps turned on* and that is what is answered in the possibly duplicate question. And yes another thing, this site works best with a single Q and A format