# How can I track my app usage?

Tags: applications, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I track app usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/how-can-i-track-app-usage)

If you're not familiar with the late Wakoopa app for desktop, it's a small utility that runs in the background and monitors what application / website I go to along with a graph of how long I've spent using said apps / websites. I have found it a valuable asset to monitoring my app usage behavior. It also helps me trim down on the applications that I hardly ever use.

Is there something like this for Android? Root-needed answers are all welcome. There was supposedly something like this already before at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.muzikant.MyTopApps but as you can tell, it's no longer available on the market. Plus, it didn't have the monitoring of frequent visited websites.

It doesn't matter if it enters the log onto the cloud (like Wakoopa did) but I would honestly prefer if it stored them offline so that I keep my data private.

Comment: Shedo, I took the freedom to re-phrase the title of your question, to prevent it from being closed as "off topic" (see [FAQ], "is there an app" belongs to OT). And as it turned out, at least for a part of what you want, you don't need another app :)

Comment: [What are my most frequently used apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18774/what-are-my-most-frequently-used-apps/18787#18787) might cover at least some of what you're looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! eldarerathis recommendation ([Spare Parts Plus!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts) now) is also worth a look, as it also offers additional settings. As for your web tracking, there are some "parental control" apps around which could do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know what app you started how often, this is easiest accomplished via your dialer (no kidding!). Just dial the "magic code" `*#*#4636#*#*`, which will open a menu like this:

[image: Statistics Menu]

Here you simply press "Usage statistics", and it will present you with a list of your apps and how often you started them.

Comment: Is this over the device's lifetime or is there some way to do last month etc?

Comment: @Bar I'm not entirely sure. AFAIK it's based on statistics from `batterystats.bin`. Definitely not *device* lifetime (once you [perform a factory reset I guess they are gone](/a/113351/16575), if you "clean flash" a ROM they are definitely gone). As the file however survives reboots, those do these stats.

Answer (score 1):

[RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com) is a service I used long ago that seems to fit your requirements. It has plugins for desktop browsers and an app for Android. It ca break down your usage according to app, time, and different criteria (e.g. Productivity, Entertainment, etc..).

You can get the Android app from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rescuetime.android).

Note: It won't be able to measure time spent on specific sites on mobile browsers.